# Numpy ndarray's min/max with axis variable

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'm a bit confused about how numpy's ndarray's min/max function with a given `axis` argument works.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(2,3,4)
x.min(axis=0)
```

produces

```
array([[[0.4139181 , 0.24235588, 0.50214552, 0.38806332],
        [0.63775691, 0.08142376, 0.69722379, 0.1968098 ],
        [0.50496744, 0.54245416, 0.75325114, 0.67245846]],

       [[0.79760899, 0.35819981, 0.5043491 , 0.75274284],
        [0.54778544, 0.5597848 , 0.52325408, 0.66775091],
        [0.71255276, 0.85835137, 0.60197253, 0.33060771]]])

array([[0.4139181 , 0.24235588, 0.50214552, 0.38806332],
       [0.54778544, 0.08142376, 0.52325408, 0.1968098 ],
       [0.50496744, 0.54245416, 0.60197253, 0.33060771]])
```

a 3x4 numpy array. I was thinking it would produce a size 2 array with the minimum for `x[0]` and `x[1]`.

Can someone explain how this min function is working?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `x.min(axis=0)`, you request the min to be computed along the axis 0, which means this dimension is aggregated into a single value and thus the output has a (3,4) shape.

What you want is to compute the min on the combined axes 1 and 2:

```
x.min(axis=(1,2))
# array([0.38344152, 0.0202184 ])
```

You can also first reshape the array to combine those two dimensions, then compute the min along this new dimension (here, 1):

```
x.reshape(2,-1).min(axis=1)
# array([0.38344152, 0.0202184 ])
```

intermediate, reshaped, array:

```
x.reshape(2,-1)

array([[0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318, 0.4236548 ,
        0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773  , 0.96366276, 0.38344152,
        0.79172504, 0.52889492],
       [0.56804456, 0.92559664, 0.07103606, 0.0871293 , 0.0202184 ,
        0.83261985, 0.77815675, 0.87001215, 0.97861834, 0.79915856,
        0.46147936, 0.78052918]])
```

used input:

```
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.rand(2,3,4)
```

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted what axis meant. For a 2D array (matrix), I thought axis = 0 corresponded to the rows and axis = 1 corresponded to the columns, but it seems axis = 0 corresponds to columns and axis = 1 corresponds to rows.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "this dimension is AGGREGATED into a single value". I don't thinkn I understand

Comment: oh never mind, I see. yeah I totally misunderstood the meaning of `axis`

Comment: Aggregation means that the function takes an array as input, performs a computation that aggregates multiple values into a single one, and returns a scalar or an array of lower dimension.

Comment: The meaning of `axis` when doing this, or `np.sum` is hard to intuit when looking at a square 2d array.  Experimenting with a (3,4) array will be clearer, since the result will be either (3,) or (4,).  Or think about what happens to a 1d array.  Using `keepdims=True` might also help visualize the action.